# print table headers only in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, header

Is it possible to print headers in Hive without the table name prefix?

I did:  `set hive.cli.print.header=true;`

and then: `select * from brands limit 3;`

the result was:

```
brands.id  brands.name brands.tag      brands.value
7     Brand      50      DeLorme
0     Brand      50      U-Line
27    Brand      50      Elcon
```

And what really wanted to get is:

```
id    name       tag      value
7     Brand      50      DeLorme
0     Brand      50      U-Line
27    Brand      50      Elcon
```

"`brands`" is a table that I created and not a main DB table.

Thanks for your help,
Nina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
```

---

> **hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names**
>
> **Default Value:** true.
>   **Added In:** Hive 0.13.0 with HIVE-6687
>
> Make column names unique in the result set by qualifying column names
>   with table alias if needed. Table alias will be added to column names
>   for queries of type "select *" or if query explicitly uses table alias
>   "select r1.x..".
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties